# Best way to create horizontal menu with fixed width

Tags: html

I wonder, what's the best way to create horizontal menu with fixed width and variable number of items?

To adjust menu to make items equally spaced on menu strip, seems the only way is to use `table width=100%` as menu wrapper and items as `td`. So they would be adjusted automatically.

Is there another solution (without `td`), considering that we don't know the number of items and, moreover, it can vary?

Comment: unordered list with the list items set to display inline

Comment: The question is not about how to create horizontal menu, but how to make items be equally adjusted

Comment: you mean equally spaced items?

Comment: right, i'll fix question

Comment: `considering that we don't know the number of items and ,moreover, it can vary?` by this line am assuming what it the width of layout? Is it responsive? let me know

Comment: No, menu is with fixed width (see first line)

Comment: what happens if you need 30 items to appear on the bar but only have 300px width?

Comment: of course we need to redesign the menu in such case. 30 items is anyway bad solution for menu) that's for what submenu are intended

Comment: the point is what you are trying to achieve is not clear. You want a fixed width menu with N many menu items, (but not 30 because thats too many??) that are all equally spaced out. You suggest that you can do it in a table. Perhaps if you paste up your table code it would be clearer what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I try to achieve that items filled all menu bar (left was on the left, right is on the right, and others are equally spaced between them). 

the question with number of items isn't relevant, we propose, that number of items allows them to fit in menu. Otherwise we should use another menu solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could give the `<ul>`/`<ol>` a `display: table` and the `<li>` a `display: table-cell`:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: table;
}

li {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8RXUw/

Answer (score 0):

Unordered list with the list items set to `display: inline`:

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
  ul li {
    display: inline;
  }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
 <li>item 1</li>
 <li>item 2</li>
 <li>item 3</li>
 <li>item 4</li>
 <li>item 5</li>
 <li>item 6</li>
</ul>
```

and if it needs to be a fixed width you can play about with the width on the `ul` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, try this:

```
.wrapper {
    width:100%; /*or fixed width*/
}
header {
    text-align:center;
}
nav {
    margin:0 auto
}
nav ul {
    list-style: none outside none;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 20px;
    margin:0;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: justify;
    cursor: default; 
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;

}
nav ul li a {
    display: inline-block; 
    padding:5px 10px;
}

ul:after { 
    content: "1";
    margin-left: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/inc1uder/VCy8L/13/

Answer (score 0):

**This days we can use the [HTML5](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-reference/html5-tags.php) and [Grid CSS](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) benefits:**

```css
menu {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
}
```

```html
  <menu>
  <menuitem>Item 1</menuitem>
  <menuitem>Item 2</menuitem>
  <menuitem>Item 3</menuitem>
  <menuitem>Item 4</menuitem>
</menu>
```

**This method has the advantage** that **styling is only suitable for the parent element** in structure and is very **easily expandable**.

**Note 1:** **The equivalent form** for this rule:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
```

is also:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
```

or

```
grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
```

**Note 2:** Of course, **we can use any other structure instead of `<menu>` and `<menuitem>` tags** (eg `<ul>` with `<li>` or nested `<div>` tags, etc.). Also instead of `<menuitem>` tag we can use also `<li>` tag with `<menu>` tag, because currently the  tag is not supported by the most of the web browsers.